# State not changing when build next.js project but is in dev server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

```
setWordGroups((prev) => {
    if (prev) {
        prev.push(prev.shift()!);
        return [...prev];
    }
});
```

This is working as spected in dev server `npm run dev`. but in production or when I build it `npm run build`
`npm run start` the state is not changing. I have also tried `JSON.perse(JSON.stringify(prev))` , deleting .next folder, purging Vercel Data Cache.

How do I fix this, it ain't trigering any useEffect depended by this state. [here's the project](https://github.com/shahrierNafis/learn-quran-vocabulary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it...

```
setWordGroups((prev) => {
  if (prev) {
    const new = [...prev];
    new.push(new.shift()!); 
    return new;
  }

  return prev;
});
```

Trying to modifying the original `wordGroups` array directly within the callback function caused the original code not to work. Modifying the original array might not be detected by React, leading to unexpected rendering behavior.